# Media stream output from camera in expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo, webrtc

I am trying to make a peer to peer video call app.
I am using expo for the front end and I want to know how to get the media stream from the mobile camera to pass it to the peer.currently this can be achieved using react-native-webrtc but expo does not support this package. So is there any alternatives to get media stream from camera ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to use react-native-webrtc now with the Expo Run Commands that went live a few weeks ago. I haven't tested this out yet but I read about it [here](https://blog.expo.io/introducing-expo-run-commands-835ae8da4813) and [here](https://twitter.com/sebastienlorber/status/1399737458804264967?s=20) where WebRTC was named specifically.

Comment: Hey thanks alot I'll check it out and post if it works.

Comment: Hi Jessica I tested it and its working thanks alot

Comment: That's awesome, glad to hear!