# Is possible use react native EXPO-CLI and implement video calling?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I need an implementation that allows me to connect two clients, one in react Js and the other in react native with expo-cli, through a video call, but I don't know if is possible to do that in these conditions. I'd like some example or alternative to solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use something called `WebRTC` , it allows you to stream audio and/or video media.

**For browser** , Read [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API) article

**For react native**, your going to need a package called `react-native-webrtc` , Read more in [This](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc) page.

Also read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68093715/media-stream-output-from-camera-in-expo-react-native)